# How to "break" remote access on Windows and rooted Android?

Tags: malware, windows, android, remote-desktop, rat

Let's say you want to "break" all remote access capabilities on your rooted Android phone and your Windows PC. What do you do or delete so remote access is truly broken and can't be used (by a hacker)?

Comment: So do you want your first question to stay up or do you want this one to survive?

Comment: Hey schroeder, you're everywhere aren't you? :) The difference is that if it's "broken" it won't work at all because it can't. I used the answers to my other question to find syntax and etc. for better defenses. Later I recalled someone attempting to play a "broken" videogame so I thought the answers to this question would be distinctly different. I was thinking "disabling explicitly implemented remote access functionality" by deleting what it needs to function at all; "bugs in the firmware and drivers" weren't on my mind at the time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see much of a difference with your previous question [How to close or block remote access backdoors?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/238512/how-to-close-or-block-remote-access-backdoors) except that it now a bit more focused by asking only for Windows and Android.

It looks like you are not asking about disabling explicitly implemented remote access functionality but anything which might allow an attacker to allow remote access. Since this might also include [bugs in the firmware and drivers](https://www.wired.com/story/broadpwn-wi-fi-vulnerability-ios-android/) the only way to disable remote access is to disable any network connectivity at all, i.e. disable network interfaces and/or put the device in some [Faraday cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage) or similar. This includes everything which might be reachable by the hacker you envision, i.e. Ethernet, WiFi, Bluetooth, USB based networking and maybe even NFC.

Of course, this makes the devices kind of unusable for most modern use cases. Given that it may be questionable if it makes even sense to harden an existing device/OS this way, or if is better to use some more specialized device with a smaller attacker surface for this specific use case instead.